# What does it mean to overload operator bool with two parameters?

Tags: c++, casting, overloading, operator-keyword

In an assignment I'm told to implement `bool operator()(const T&, const T&)` for some class. Overloading `bool operator` is meant to allow the object to be implicitly cast to `bool`. What does it mean to overload it with two parameters? How are these parameters passed on the calling side? How is this used?

Comment: What exactly do you have to overload? `operator bool` or `operator ()`? In the title/text of your question you talk about `operator bool`, but the declaration you posted is for `operator ()`. So, what is it supposed to be? What exactly does it say in the assignment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not "operator bool", but `operator()`, with two `T` arguments, returning a `bool`. In other words, it is a *binary predicate*. You can use it like this:

```
struct Foo
{
  bool operator()(const T&, const T&); // should probably be const
};

... 
Foo f;
T t1, t2;
bool b = f(t1, t2);
```

Comment: Oh.. so it's simply overloading the `()` operator... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You confuse `operator bool` with `operator()` with return type bool. The assignment is about the latter.